Format date from YYYYMMDD to YYMMDD in Javascript
I have this code which shows the year in YYYYMMDD format. I would like the output to be in YYMMDD format. Basically to replace 2014 to 14 only.


let date = new Date();
let timeNow = new Date(date.valueOf()-60*1000*date.getTimezoneOffset()).toISOString().substring(0, 10).replace(/-/g,"");
console.log(timeNow);



PS: I'm in a +5:30 timezone if that matters. My initial code was without the whistles but someone commented that I have to use getTimezoneOffset else there may be a difference of 5.5 hours and create problems in the future:


let date = new Date();
let timeToday = new Date(Date.now()).toISOString().slice(0, 10).replace(/-/g,"");
console.log(timeToday);




Replace substring(0, 10) with substring(2, 10)

Beware. How would you then know the difference between 1914 and 2014? Y2K problem.

@RokoC.Buljan What do you mean 50 and 50? Please elaborate further

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Year_2000_problem

@RokoC.Buljan I don't think my code will run for 76 years to make it to the year 2100 to have this problem :) or am I missing something?

Just don't shorten-format years. What about a year in the past? Say 1924?

I understand and Thank you for pointing it out. I read about this when I was a kid but never knew about this problem.

To convert the date format from YYYYMMDD to YYMMDD, you can modify your code to extract the last two digits of the year.


let date = new Date();
let timeNow = new Date(date.valueOf() - 60 * 1000 * date.getTimezoneOffset())
.toISOString()
.substring(0, 10)
.replace(/-/g, "")
.substring(2); // Extract the last two digits of the year
console.log(timeNow);



The substring(2) method removes the first two characters of the string, effectively converting YYYYMMDD to YYMMDD.

If you do the replace first then you only need one substring call, i.e. ....toISOString().replace(/-/g, '').substring(2,8). ;-)

There are any number of ways to format a Date, however the method in the OP is not a good way to go about it. It seems inefficient to use a method that creates a timestamp with the wrong offset, so (somewhat confusing) corrections need to be made to get the required offset when the Date object can produce timestamps with the required offset with no help.
There are plenty of options with far less code and simpler logic, e.g.
Using basic Date methods:


const formatYMD = (d = new Date()) => {
  // Pad numbers to 2 digits
  let z = (n) => ('0'+ n).slice(-2);
  return z(d.getFullYear()) + z(d.getMonth()+1) + z(d.getDate());
}

console.log(formatYMD());



Using toLocaleString:


const formatYMD = (d = new Date()) => d.toLocaleString('sv').slice(2, 10).replace(/\D/g,'');

console.log(formatYMD());



Using Intl.DateTimeFormat:


const formatYMD = (function() {

  // Keep formatter in a closure so more efficient
  let f = new Intl.DateTimeFormat('sv', {
    year: '2-digit',
    month: '2-digit',
    day: '2-digit'
  });

  // Actual function
  return (d = new Date()) => f.format(d).replace(/\D/g, '');
})();

console.log(formatYMD());




Try this one:


let date = new Date();
let timeNow = new Date(date.valueOf() - 60 * 1000 * date.getTimezoneOffset()).toISOString().slice(2, 10).replace(/-/g, "");
console.log(timeNow);



